# Counter of unique files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

I ran a program many times with output that was (slightly) non-deterministic. Each time, I printed the output to a file. I now have a directory of many text files (95,034), which probably have something like 4 different unique outputs. I would love to see the output in a format like this:

```
 A (50,000)
 B (30,000)
 C (10,000)
 D  (5,034)
```

But even just seeing the contents of A,B,C,D (the four different possible outputs) would be great. I don't have time to manually dedupe 90,000 files. So how can I count or list the unique text files in a directory? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, maybe this is what you are looking for `grep -r "A" | wc -l`, which wich will give you the number of files that containt "A" (assuming "A" appears only once in each file)

Comment: Do you have those four possible outputs at your disposal or their content is arbitrary and subject to change every run?

Comment: You can find dupes with `fdupes`

Comment: Could you post an example outputfile for each of the 4 possible outputs?

Comment: Do you want to get a list, or do you rather want to remove the duplicates right away and keep only one of them?

Comment: @markgraf Let's assume the output changes every run. But the outputs are something like "A\na", "B\nb", "C\nc", "D\nd". So I want to see a count of the number of files containing a, b, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding slightly on @Isaac's solution ....

Assuming `bash` syntax, and given:

```
$ find test -type f
test/AA
test/A
test/C
test/CC
test/B
test/D
```

where files A and AA are identical, as are C and CC;

This is an incrementally more effective command pipeline:

```
$ find test -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "md5sum < {}" \; |
    sort -k1,1 |
    uniq --count
      2 102f2ac1c3266e03728476a790bd9c11  -
      1 4c33d7f68620b7b137c0ca3385cb6597  -
      1 88178a003e2305475e754a7ec21d137d  -
      2 c7a739d5538cf472c8e87310922fc86c  -
```

The remaining problem now is that the md5 hashes don't tell you which files are A, B, C or D.  That can be solved, although it's a slight bit fiddly.

First, move your files into a subdirectory, or move your PWD up one directory if that's more convenient.  In my example, I'm working in `.` and the files are in `test/`.

I'll propose that you identify one each of the four file types, and copy them to file A, B, C and D (and beyond if you need to, up to Z):

```
$ cp -p test/file1002 ./A
...
$ cp -p test/file93002 ./N
```

etc.  We can now build a hash table that defines the md5 hashes of each unique output file A-Z:

```
$ for file in [A-Z]; do 
      printf "s/%s/%s/\n" "$(md5sum < $file )" "$file"; 
done
s/102f2ac1c3266e03728476a790bd9c11  -/A/
s/4c33d7f68620b7b137c0ca3385cb6597  -/B/
s/c7a739d5538cf472c8e87310922fc86c  -/C/
s/88178a003e2305475e754a7ec21d137d  -/D/
```

Notice that the hash table looks like `sed` syntax.  Here's why:

Let's run the same `find ... md5sum` pipeline above:

```
$ find test -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "md5sum < {}" \; |
    sort -k1,1 |
    uniq --count
```

... and pipe it through a `sed` process that uses the hash table above to replace the hash values with the prototype file names.  The `sed` command on its own would be:

```
sed -f <(
    for file in [A-Z]; do 
        printf "s/%s/%s/\n" "$(md5sum < "$file")" "$file"; 
    done
)
```

So to connect it all together:

```
$ find test -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "md5sum < {}" \; |
    sort -k1,1 |
    uniq --count |
    sed -f <(
        for file in [A-Z]; do 
            printf "s/%s/%s/\n" "$(md5sum < "$file")" "$file"; 
        done
    )
  2 A
  1 B
  1 D
  2 C
```

If you see output like this:

```
  2 A
  1 B
  1 5efa8621f70e1cad6aba9f8f4246b383  -
  1 D
  2 C
```

That means there is a file in `test/` which has an MD5 value that doesn't match your files A-D.  In other words, there is an `E` output file format out there somewhere.  Once you find it (`md5sum test/* | grep 5efa8621f70e1cad6aba9f8f4246b383`) you can copy it to E and re-run:

```
$ cp -p test/file09876 ./E
$ find test -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c "md5sum < {}" \; |
    sort -k1,1 |
    uniq --count |
    sed -f <(
        for file in [A-Z]; do 
            printf "s/%s/%s/\n" "$(md5sum < "$file")" "$file"; 
        done
    )
  2 A
  1 B
  1 E
  1 D
  2 C
```

Comment: Thank you, this is super thorough!

Comment: Ideally the algorithm would automatically find an example of each unique output file and create the A..Z files for you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a big fan of GNU `datamash` (https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/).  Here's a sample output from a mocked up set of files I created and ran this command on:

```
$ md5sum * | datamash -W -s -g 1 count 2 -f
5591dadf0051bee654ea41d962bc1af0    junk1   27
9c08c31b951a1a1e0c3a38effaca5863    junk2   17
f1e5cbfade7063a0c4fa5083fd36bf1a    junk3   7
```

There are 27 files with the hash 5591..., and one of them is "junk1".  (Similarly 17 files that are the same as "junk2", and 7 for "junk3").

The `-W` says use whitespace as field delimiter.  The `-s -g 1` says sort and group by field 1 (which is the hash).  The `count` could have been either field 1 or 2, doesn't matter.

The `-f` says "print the entire input line".  This has a quirk, in that when you are printing aggregated results, it only prints the full line for the *first* line in each group that it found.  In this case that works out fine, because it gives us one of the filenames involved in each dup-set, instead of all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sort` and `uniq` for this.  From within the folder where the files reside, enter:

```
find . -type f | awk '{ print "tr \\\\n @ < " $0 "; echo "}' | sh | sort | uniq --count
```

(Replace `uniq --count` by `uniq -c` if not using `uniq` from GNU coreutils.)

That should give you the results in one go.  For simplicity and speed (avoiding hashes) we translate the newlines to `@` -- this could be any single character not part of the original file.

(This assumes that files in sub-folders, if they exist, are to be included.  Another assumption is that there is no `@` character in the file.  If not please comment and I'll adjust the command accordingly.)

Comment: This also assumes that each file has exact one line of output. (the question indicates that this is the case, but you might want to add that information). You could also use `-exec cat -- {} +` instead of piping to `xargs` which gives some overhead.

Comment: @pLumo Thanks, added that note.  The `-exec cat` ought to be similar but I can type it faster my way. I do not believe there is a noticeable overhead (if at all) on a multi CPU system but it may be interesting to test.

Comment: Fair enough. It shouldn't make a huge difference that is right.

Comment: Each file has up to 4 lines of output, I think.

Comment: @jxmorris12 OK, this version should work with multi-line files.  It avoids hashes for speed.  The final output still has newlines converted to `@` which is probably convenient, anyway?

Comment: You'll get _really_ interesting results with files that have names such as `whatever; rm -rf *` (just don't try that particular one).

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me, I just had to replace `uniq --count` with `uniq -c` on my system. :)

Comment: @jxmorris12 I am glad it worked, added the note on `-c` and am looking forward to your upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash map to gather all unique files. The hash depends on the contents, so only the files with unique contents get an entry in the hash map.

```
declare -A unique_files
for file in *; do 
    unique_files["$(md5sum "$file" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)"]="$file"
done
echo "${unique_files[@]}"
```

Comment: Though it will be pretty slow for a large number of file, the idea is good. But it will overwrite the value with the last `$file` that it finds for each md5sum. Btw: You should doublequote `$file` after `md5sum`.

Comment: @pLumo Do you think it is faster to first check for existence, and only than add the file?